# Cost of updating Web Site hosted on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a static web site hosted on S3 in the free tier. This tier gives me "2,000 Put, Copy, Post or List Requests of Amazon S3" which I am regularly exceeding.

Given that my web site has 92 files in it when rendered using Next.js and I keep a test and prod version of the web site, does this mean that every time I deploy a new version it counts as 184 updates to S3?

Extra info: I do a very simple deployment: build on a local Jenkins, saving a tar file to an artefacts S3 bucket, untar to to local then use a "aws s3 sync" command to copy to my bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re correct, this limit counts towards individual files that you’re uploading.

Remember that AWS S3 sync also performs ListObjects when it executes so this too will count (although this is a paginated request that returns 1000 objects at a time so it counts as one).

The sync command should only copy new and modified files so you should only see these requests count in the free tier limit.